# "Being left" vs "left"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Even if *being* is not used in this sentence, does it not give the same meaning?

> A prince becomes all powerful, but still his priests fear God more than they do him. There is only one ***being*** left for the prince to conquer - God himself. And so he declares war on God.

Would the following have the same meaning

> There is only one left...

Comment: Here _being_ is a noun, meeaning a living entity. Without it it would be grammatical, but vague, because the _one_ (which would then be a pronoun) would not be restricted in meaning.

Comment: Old-fashioned writing used to capitalise 'Being' when discussing God.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "There is only one left for the prince to conquer" sounds better for a literary context because it adds suspense, which is quickly resolved with the next clause. This wording, as Colin pointed out, is ambiguous, but I think that's the point.

The meaning remains much the same.